# Android-app Feed has a weird notion of a time-line

Tags: bug, android-app

The "Feed" displays questions/activities sorted as "newest first", with categories

- just now
- earlier today
- yesterday
- ...

Now, looking at the screenshots from just now (Thu, 3rd Sept 2015) I notice:

- "Check security mode..." (presumably from *yesterday*) has been asked **3 hours ago**
- "One or more prerequisites ..." (presumably from *Earlier this month*) has been asked **2 hours ago**
- "Does CVE-2015-...." (presumably from *Earlier this month*) has been asked and edited **1 hour ago**
- The comment on my meta.SE question (presumably from *Earlier this month*) has been made in **early August** - now we have September
- The same applies for "XSS for stealing Cookies...."

[image: screenshot 1] 
[image: screenshot 2]