# Can we restrict the size of an image?

Tags: support, markdown, images

Especially questions containing screenshots from the android-app are somewhat difficult to read in the web browser, because the screenshot is taking the width of the complete body.

<sub>(see for instance [Android-app Feed has a weird notion of a time-line](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/264719/android-app-feed-has-a-weird-notion-of-a-time-line), where the screenshots are ridiculously huge)</sub>

It would be nice to be able to tell the system to display both screenshots side-by-side or just to restrict the size to something sensible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*You* can change the size yourself.

- Adding `s` to the end of the image link will make it `s`mall
- Adding `m` to the end of the image link will make it `m`edium size
- Adding `l` to the end of the image link will make it `l`arge
- Use the HTML `<img>` tag with the `height` and `width` attributes

Eg. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCfgS.png --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCfgSm.png for a smaller image.

There are a few more letters you can add, see more at http://api.imgur.com/models/image#thumbs. Quoting from that link:

```
| Thumbnail Suffix | Thumbnail Name   | Thumbnail Size | Keeps Image Proportions |
|------------------|------------------|----------------|-------------------------|
| s                | Small Square     | 90x90          | No                      |
| b                | Big Square       | 160x160        | No                      |
| t                | Small Thumbnail  | 160x160        | Yes                     |
| m                | Medium Thumbnail | 320x320        | Yes                     |
| l                | Large Thumbnail  | 640x640        | Yes                     |
| h                | Huge Thumbnail   | 1024x1024      | Yes                     |
```

---

> [image]

goes to:

> [image]

---

In my experience, for extremely large images (like the one you mention), even adding `l` will make it smaller. Eg:

> [image]

Comment: great - thank you -- where can the documentation for this feature be found?

Comment: @guntbert The HTML part: http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images. The appending a letter part: http://api.imgur.com/models/image#thumbs

Comment: One should also be aware than `m` and smaller sizes will render most of the text unreadable due to aggressive compression by imgur. For images containing text, it's either `l` or HTML.